# Can LESS generate images like Compass (Sass)?

Tags: javascript, rubygems, sass, less, compass-sass

I'm comparing capabilities of LESS with Compass(Sass)

To make cross browser transparent background in Compass we can use this method http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/cross-browser-rgba-support/ which can generate transparent image too along with rgba code.

> [compass-rgbapng plugin](https://github.com/aaronrussell/compass-rgbapng) for providing cross-browser compatible RGBA
>   support by creating transparent PNGs on the fly for browsers that
>   don't support RGBA. Uses the pure Ruby ChunkyPNG library for hassle
>   free install and deployment.

```
sudo gem install compass-rgbapng

require "rgbapng"

@import "rgbapng";


background: url('/images/rgbapng/000000bf.png?1282127952');
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

Is it possible to do same with LESS? I think not because LESS is based on JavaScript and JavaScript is not as capable as ruby. Am i right?

Comment: _JavaScript is not as capable as ruby_ is not something I would agree with at all.  More the the point is if a tool already exists for this  in LESS/JS similar to the one you mention for SASS/Ruby.

Comment: @AlexWayne - It uses the pure Ruby ChunkyPNG library

Comment: Nitpicking here but JavaScript is a turing complete language so it's disingenuous to say it's not as capable. The browser implementation of JavaScript cannot generate images to my knowledge but you are more than able to generate images using a server side implementation such as NodeJs.

Comment: Actually, you can generate an image with pure JS. **You just need one tiny browser feature, Data URLs**. Files are just an array of bytes with a defined structure, and with Javascript you can work with binary strings to build any kind of structure you want. The only problem is that from Javascript you cannot generate file references, except with the use of Data URLs. The problem would be to ensure support for Data URLs on all IE versions targeted, and the fact that **this solution is kind of horrible, as it introduces A LOT of overhead** to make just a fancy solid-color transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: not with just the LESS library.

You can combine the server side plugin with a LESS script. You can make a LESS class that generates the CSS style:

```
background: url('/images/rgbapng/000000bf.png?1282127952');
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

I'm not sure how that library works, but the only important part i can see is the name of the PNG being the RGBA value hex-encoded. Being just that, I've made a LESS script that allows using that URL schema to take advantage of the server-side image builder:

```
@compass-url: '/images/rgbapng/'; 

.rgba-background(@r, @g, @b, @a) {
    @date-nocache: `new Date().getTime().toString()`;
    @colorInt: floor(@a * 255) + 256 * (@b + (256 * (@g + 256 * @r)));
    @colorHex: `(parseInt("@{colorInt}") + Math.pow(256,4)).toString(16).slice(1,9)`;

    background: "@{compass-url}@{colorHex}.png?@{date-nocache}";
    background: rgba(@r, @g, @b, @a);
}
```

This scripts creates the class/function rgba-background in LESS, allowing you to anotate your LESS class like:

```
.yourClass {
    .rgba-background(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

If you plan to use this accross multiple less scripts, it would be adviceable to extract it to another file, and use the @import directive wherever you want to use it.

If the URL generated is more complex that i thought, please provide some additional info on how to build that URL, so we can see if this can be resolved using LESS.